# HTTPS URL Not Working in PHP

Tags: xml, https

I am working on online shopping store at SMS Project, the purpose is when customer place an order than system should automatically send an SMS at customer provided number during the checkout.

SMS company give us API documentation for this. First they required the authentication process that generate the session id and we use the session id to send an sms to the user.

Authentication Code:

```
$msisdn = 'abc';
$password = 'xyz';
$session_req="https://telenorcsms.com.pk:27677/corporate_sms2/api/auth.jsp?msisdn=".$msisdn."&password=".$password;

$xmlResponse = simplexml_load_file('https://telenorcsms.com.pk:27677/corporate_sms2/api/auth.jsp?msisdn=abc&password=xyz');
    $sessionID = $xmlResponse->corpsms->data;       
    var_dump($sessionID);
    echo "Session ID: " . $sessionID;
```

Now the problem is i am unable to get the session id. When i use the `var_dump($sessionID);` than NULL is output and if i try to display on screen by using the `echo "Session ID: " . $sessionID;` nothing is show. If i USE the `header('Location:'.$session_req);` code than below is the response of above URL and show the session id successfully.

Success Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<corpsms> 
    <command>Auth_request</command> 
    <data>Session ID</data> 
    <response>OK</response>
</corpsms>
```

Session id is store in the XML structure and its in different URL but my files are at different URL. (http://example.com/neworder.php). 
Can anyone let me know how can i store the Session id in a variable in PHP to use it further to send an sms? 
**Important point is the session ID will expire after 30 minutes of inactivity.**
Below is the URL to send an SMS by using the session id:

```
https://telenorcsms.com.pk:27677/corporate_sms2/api/sendsms.jsp?session_id=xxxx&to=923xxxxxxxxx&text=xxxx&mask=xxxx
```

thanks in advance.

MUNEEB

Comment: Have you tried using curl ?

Comment: yes but not find the solution because  the purpose is to get the session id value.

Comment: $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $session_req);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  // For SSL Certificate 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  $tokens = explode("\n", trim($response));
  curl_close($ch);
  var_dump($response);

Comment: What was the output of 
var_dump($response);

Comment: If it was the same xml you can parse it and get the value using  PHP SimpleXML Parser

https://www.w3schools.com/Php/php_xml_simplexml_read.asp

Comment: out put is bool(false)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Store the XML response into PHP variable (Let's call it **$xmlResponse**)
- Easily you can get the XML response by submitting the API url associated with its parameters to **[file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)** function. Then convert it to XML object using the function [**simplexml_load_string()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php)

  ```
  $xmlResponseString = file_get_contents($apiUrl)
  $xmlResponse = simplexml_load_string($xmlResponseString);
  ```
- That response can be used as [**SimpleXMLElement**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php).
- Session ID should be accessed on this way:

  ```
  $sessionID = $xmlResponse->corpsms->data;
  ```

Comment: thanks for the answer! but the problem is how can i execute the URL in PHP $session_req="https://telenorcsms.com.pk:27677/corporate_sms2/api/auth.jsp?msisdn=".$msisdn."&password=".$password;

Comment: simplexml_load_file() will execute the url and return back to you the XML response as SimpleXMLElement.

Comment: hi I tried it but sessionid not get: $msisdn = 'abc';
  $password = 'xyz';
  $xmlResponse = simplexml_load_file('https://telenorcsms.com.pk:27677/corporate_sms2/api/auth.jsp?msisdn=".$msisdn."&password=".$password');
  $sessionID = $xmlResponse->corpsms->data;
  
  echo "Session ID: " . $sessionID;

Comment: Well, please update your question and put there your trials SimpleXMLEelement with code in order to help you in a better way.

Comment: You don't get the session ID because request GET parameters are wrong, so <data> tag will be filled by the error message code. Please what is the value of $sessionID ? try to print (echo) it.

Comment: nothing is displayed when i try to (echo) $sessionID. but when i try to use var_dump($xmlResponse); than bool(false) is output.

Comment: may be the error due to https. i still didn't get the session id

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue when executing the script at hostgator server, but its just working fine here in my localhost server. you just need to enable OPENSSL extension in WAMP or XAMP server.

Comment: Solved: Follow these steps on hosting server

1) enable OPENSSL 
2) Ask your hosting provider to open port 27677 for external request.